# Java - Describing the correct faces (Winding)

Tags: java, opengl, geometry, lwjgl

Engine : LWJGL

SO , I am wondering , how do I draw a triangle's back face? I know there is something going on  with the

```
glTexCoord();
```

method(s), but I can not understand in which way I need to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The facing of a triangle has *nothing* to do with texture coords. It is solely defined by the winding of the vertices in window space.

By default, GL uses the rule that if the three vertices (in the order as they are specified when drawing) are seen - in the final picture - in counter-clockwise order, then this is treated as the front face. This facing rule can be changed via [`glFrontFace()`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glFrontFace.xml). Furthermore, the GL can be told do never draw a specific face via `glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE)`. Which faces are culled is controlled by [`glCullFace()`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glCullFace.xml). Typically, *backface culling* is used for closed objects (wihtout transparency), as in such cases, the back-facing triangles are never seen and do not need to be processed.

So to control the facing of your triangles, the order in which the vertices are specified does matter. Furthermore, the transformations you use define which side you are actually seeing.

The winding should especially be *consistent* inbetween and across objects. Two triangles sharing an edge, like triangles A,B,C and B,C,D, have a consitent winding if the shared edge is specified in mutually ireverse order. That is, if you specify the first triangles vertices in the order A,B,C, you must specify the vertices of latter triangle in a way such that C,B is used, like C,B,D or D,C,B, or B,D,C.

Comment: So , for better performance , leave the defaults. Is cull face enabled by default? Also , the fact that I don't understand is how OGL determines if it is CW/CCW.

Comment: Well. Face culling is disabled by default. To the winding: one way would be to calculate the [signed area](http://geomalgorithms.com/a01-_area.html) of the window space vertices (projected to 2D, so ignoring the z component). The sign will tell the winding order. This is usually calcluated at the triangle setup stage, just before the rasterization is done.